# Handle multiple Nytimes path response with common base response class

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc

I'm trying to implement NYTimes APIs. As of now, the idea is simple, just hit the desired endpoint from the application and call the NYTimes API behind the scene.
But problem comes here, I have selected few paths(Top stories, Movie Review, Books...etc) and they all return different results array.

I would like to create a common BaseResponse class to handle the response of all the paths, if possible.

So far I've written the basic structure:

```
public class BaseResponse {
    private String status;
    private String copyright;
    private int numResults;
    List<Results> results;
}
```

I will enhance this with getters & setters as well as constructor.

Is there a way to handle various results using a common class?
If not then how can I model the response for each path?

Comment: Set Results as an empty abstract class and provide implementations for each type of result.